# How do I process a file from a memory stream?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am posting one or more files from my Vue.js frontend. It's being done as such:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate v-if="isInitial || isSaving">
    <div class="dropbox">
        <input type="file" multiple :name="uploadFieldName" :disabled="isSaving" @change="filesChange($event.target.name, $event.target.files); fileCount = $event.target.files.length" accept=".json" class="input-file">
        <p v-if="isInitial">
            Drag files here to begin <br> or click to browse
        </p>
        <p v-if="isSaving">
            Uploading {{ fileCount }} files...
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I then post it via this method:

```
function upload(formData) {
    const url = `${BASE_URL}/api/upload`;
    return axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
    })
}
```

Which seems to do the job.

Following Microsoft's own guide, I have created the following endpoint:

```
namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/api/upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

            // full path to file in temp location
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

            // process uploaded files <-- What does this entail? How do I access the stream?

            return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
        }
    }
}
```

I am somewhat new to C# coming from Java: What does the [Microsoft docs found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1) mean when they say "process uploaded files"?

How do I access them from the memory stream? Why is the comment outside the for loop - if I had to do stuff with the files, it should be on it - or not?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "`process`". Save to disk? Open and read content? Send in email? Copy data from stream to database? Process could mean anything....

Comment: Fair enough - let's say process meaning access the filename, and read the content?

Comment: That's not the best example though. If you upload two files, the second will overwrite the first one since the example code uses a single file path

Comment: It is literally the example from Microsoft's own docs.. I am more than happy to be told if there are better ways for sure..

Comment: the bit where it says using (var stream = new filestream(filepath, filemode.create)){ await formfile.copytoasync(stream);}  saves the file to the disk ...

Comment: Just see the documentation for IFormFile, [FileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.filename?view=aspnetcore-2.1). And file content you can get as a Stream using [OpenReadStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_OpenReadStream) or the way you already have it in your code now.

Comment: If you tell us what you want to do with the posted file I think we can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow that Microsoft example is horrible.

Assuming you have a single `IFormFile` named `formFile` (I trust you be able to write that loop yourself), the simplest way to get to the barebones is:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    // do what you want with the bytes
}
```

You just copied the bytes twice, in the original formfile, in the stream and then into the byte array, so when you have more experience in .NET you may want to optimize it a bit. Maybe proceed your processing with the memory stream directly instead of the byte array.

Comment: It's horrible indeed. I wasn't able to even get the files to hit the endpoint, IFormFile was always empty. I have to parse it as `.... UploadFiles(IFormCollection collection)`. Now it actually has a count, and content.. Thanks for your advice I

Comment: @cbll Hi, I have similar problem. Where did you use `UploadFiles(IFormCollection collection)`? Somewhere in `using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())`? Because I dont get it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Microsoft docs may be a bit misleading.

```
foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            // here you have access to each individual file
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `using` statement, you can manipulate the `stream` object, i.e. save it out to its unique file path, process data within the file (if a `.csv`), etc. The question is a bit broad but the Microsoft article may be a bit misleading to you.

Comment: So where you put the comment, I simply call `formFile` and I have access to it? Or is it then stream? Oh and using their example it says it receives zero files when debugging.. Something is up. :-(

Comment: You dont really need the FileStream unless you intend to save it to disk. You can just work with the formFile directly.

Comment: @cbll the `formFile` object is type `IFormFile.` that may be an internal type to you? I couldn't find a reference to it in the .NET documentation. The `stream` object is a `FileStream`. Depending on what you are doing, this `stream` has what you need. See this link for documentation on the `FileStream` class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2