# Parse FormData [] with array of files - to Controller with saving to PSQL

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

Good day,

There is MVC backend - How solution should be designed for this type of problem?

So FE send this array of files:

```
FormData:[
    file0: (binary)
    file1: (binary)
    file2: (binary)
]
```

Then on BE Side there is  **Controller**:

Currently solutions store those files to filesystem.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("file")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(files);
        Console.WriteLine(size);

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", formFile.FileName);

                using var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath);
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }

        // Process uploaded files
        // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size });
    }
```

There is a model with that Files (it should have more properties in future)

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Files { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The question is: How map this array of binary object to Example model and store this Materials data in database(postgress) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your problem can be distilled down to two different questions:

1. [How do I get a byte[] from IFormFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517482/how-do-i-process-a-file-from-a-memory-stream)?

```
foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        
        var model = new Model
        {
            Name = formFile.Name,
            Files = memoryStream.ToArray()
        };
        
        // add model to database
    }
}
```

2. How do I save a `byte[]` in PostgreSQL?

Using [Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html), you can directly map a `byte[]` in C# to a `bytea` column in PostgreSQL.

Comment: So in each iteration the Model is creating, and it's possible after converting add this to PostgreSQL column ?

Where should i include this logic in Service or Controller?

What if array of files is only property of another model?

Comment: @PiotrŻak You could add the models to a list in the initial loop, and then insert them later on. I generally try to keep controllers as thin as possible, so I'd say this should be elsewhere but that's entirely up to you. I'm not sure what you mean by the last question, but it shouldn't be any different if it's on another model.